# How can I remove the Shadow of the draggable item in the Angular bootstrap modal?

Tags: css, angular, drag-and-drop, bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap

When I want to drag one item in the bootstrap modal dialog it makes a shadow of the item under the backdrop.
How can I remove shadow?

The following image shows I'm dragging the '**Personal Details**' button.

[image]